# Как вывести циклом вложенную структуру?

Tags: python-3.x, циклы

Есть переменная и она хранит вот такую структуру:

```
a = [
    {
        "key": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            ...
        ]
    },
    {...},
    ...
]
```

попытался вот так:

```
for i in a:
    for k, v in i:
        for j in k:
            print (j)
```

получил ошибку:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Так то просто `.items()` нужно брать у словаря, по умолчанию словарь итерируется по его ключам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [{"key": [0, 1, 2] },
    {"key1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,{"subkey":[1,2]}]}
    ]

def p(a):
    if isinstance(a,dict):
        for k,z in a.items():
            p(k)
            p(z)
    elif isinstance(a,list):
        for l in a:
            p(l)
    else:
        print(a)
        return
p(a)
```

---

```
key
0
1
2
key1
0
1
2
3
4
subkey
1
2
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

#### Не циклом конечно, но как вариант.

*Самым большим плюсом этого решения является то, что из формата `yaml` можно обратно собрать Ваш объект.*

`pip install PyYaml`

```py
import yaml

a = [
    {"key": [0, 1, 2]},
    {"key1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, {"subkey": [1, 2]}]},
    {"key25": [0, 4, 2, 10, 4, {"subkey": [1, 6, 9]}]},
    {"key48": [0, {"subkey": [11, 62, 80]}, 2, 10, 4, {"subkey": [1, 6, 9]}]},
]

with open('result.yaml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    yaml.dump(
        a,
        f,
        sort_keys=False
    )
```

---

`result.yaml`

```yaml
- key:
  - 0
  - 1
  - 2
- key1:
  - 0
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - subkey:
    - 1
    - 2
- key25:
  - 0
  - 4
  - 2
  - 10
  - 4
  - subkey:
    - 1
    - 6
    - 9
- key48:
  - 0
  - subkey:
    - 11
    - 62
    - 80
  - 2
  - 10
  - 4
  - subkey:
    - 1
    - 6
    - 9
```

Если на печать то так:

```py
import yaml
import io

buf = io.StringIO()

yaml.dump(
    a,
    buf,
    sort_keys=False
)

print(
    buf.getvalue()
)
```